# List folder content with Vala

Tags: linux, glib, vala

I'm trying to do a basic task: list the contents of a folder to a string array or a `List<string>` or something iterable. But it seems so tricky and I can't find what I need in the API.

My current code:

```cs
using GLib;
using Gtk;

class Demo.HelloWorld : GLib.Object {
    public static int main(string[] args) {
        File docsets = File.new_for_path (Environment.get_home_dir () + 
                "/.local/share/zeal/docsets");
        try {
            GDir* t = g_dir_open(Environment.get_home_dir ());
        } catch (FileError e) {
            stderr.printf ("%s\n", e.message);
        }
        stdout.printf(Environment.get_home_dir ()+"\n");
        stdout.printf("Hello, World\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am compiling with: `valac main.vala --pkg gtk+-3.0` and I got the following error:

```
main.vala:27.6-27.14: error: The type name `GLib.GDir' could not be found
                GLib.GDir* t = g_dir_open(Environment.get_home_dir ());
```

I tried  looking on 
https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.42/glib-File-Utilities.html and 
http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.Log.FILE, it looked pretty simple at the beginning.

Thanks for your help.

For more global context: I wish to give a try to a Synapse (launchpad.net/synapse-project) plugin.

Comment: You found it out yourself in your answer, but maybe this is helpful for someone else: GLib classes in C/C++ code are prefixed with a `G`. In Vala you have to drop that prefix, e.g. `GDir` becomes `GLib.Dir` (or just `Dir` as GLib ist always used by default) instead.

Comment: Similarly `g_dir_open ()` becomes `Dir.open ()`, also you shouldn't use pointers in Vala. Vala is using references with automatic reference counting instead. Additionally you can use type inference so you line would be shorter written as `var t = Dir.open (...);`

Comment: Thanks a thousands time for these advices !!! Vala looks a really good developpment choice whereas the namespaces are looking are a bit confusing :D

Answer (score 2):

I've finally found some example at: http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.Dir

I have the following code:

```cs
class Demo.HelloWorld : GLib.Object {
    public static int main(string[] args) {
        File docsets = File.new_for_path (Environment.get_home_dir () +
                "/.local/share/zeal/docsets");
        try {
            string directory = "./";
            Dir dir = Dir.open (directory, 0);
            string? name = null;
            while ((name = dir.read_name ()) != null) {
                string path = Path.build_filename (directory, name);
                string type = "";

                if (FileUtils.test (path, FileTest.IS_REGULAR)) {
                    type += "| REGULAR ";
                }
                if (FileUtils.test (path, FileTest.IS_SYMLINK)) {
                    type += "| SYMLINK ";
                }
                if (FileUtils.test (path, FileTest.IS_DIR)) {
                    type += "| DIR ";
                }
                if (FileUtils.test (path, FileTest.IS_EXECUTABLE)) {
                    type += "| EXECUTABLE ";
                }
                stdout.printf ("%s\t%s\n", name, type);
            }
        } catch (FileError err) {
            stderr.printf (err.message);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I hope this will help someone.

Comment: Are you sure this code works correctly? You are creating a `File` object, but you are not using it. Also shouldn't the `directory` string variable contain your docsets path instead?

Comment: Yes this code works (i'm not the author, so..) and it is just for the proof of concept of course i'm using the docsets instead of the directory string